# Applying CSS3 transforms to a glyph

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to apply a CSS transform to a icon (glyph) in a `:before` pseudo element.

Ultimately, my goal is to simply "flip" the icon with a `transform: scale(-1, 1)`, however I can't seem to get *any* transform to work on a glyph within a `:before` pseudo-element.

Here is a simple example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style>
        .icon 
        { }

        .icon::before {
            content: "X";
            color: white;
            font-size: 11pt;

            transform: scale(5);
        }
    </style>

<body>

    <div style = "padding: 1em; background: black; width: 200px; height: 200px">
        <div class = "icon">

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Link to fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/729yspsp/1/**

In this example, I'm using a simple `X` character instead of the actual glyph, for the purpose of demonstration.

As you can see, no transform is applied to the glyph.

So what am I doing wrong here?

Note: I'm using a modern version of Chrome (Chrome 37), so this isn't a browser incompatibility issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [**CSS Transforms Module Level 1**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#terminology)
>
> A transformable element is an element whose layout is governed by the CSS box model which is either a block-level or [atomic inline-level element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#x13), or whose display property computes to table-row, table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-cell, or table-caption.

Thus, the `transform` property doesn't have an effect on strictly inline-level elements.

Pseudo elements are `inline` by default.

You could set the `display` to `inline-block`<sup>1</sup> or `block` and it will work as expected.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/4bgf76cq/)

```
.icon::before {
    content: "X";
    display: inline-block;
    transform: scale(5, 2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(5, 2);
    -moz-transform: scale(5, 2);
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Thereby making it an [atomic inline-level box](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#x13).